# Prism 6 UriQuery class missing?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-6

Does anyone know what happened to the `UriQuery` class in Prism 6? just following a tutorial and it says it was under `Microsoft.Practices.Prism` but as the namespaces have all changed I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `UriQuery` was renamed to `NavigationParameters`. You can find it in the namespace `Prism.Regions` (Assembly `Prism.Wpf`). This was changed in [Version 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430871(v=pandp.40).aspx)

> The UriQuery class was renamed to NavigationParameters, it keeps the same functionality as before, and adds support for passing object parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped. Where did it say this? I was on the project site and looked through the Wiki etc but couldn't find anything on the UriQuery change.

Comment: @Gaz83 this was done by Microsoft before is was open sourced. see the link in my answer